# Git for Perforce users

Tags: git, perforce

I've been using Perforce for a number of years. I'd like to switch to using git for my personal code, but all of the git tutorials that I've seen either assume that you'e a complete source control n00b (which makes them incredibly tedious) or that you're used to svn (which I'm not).

I know p4, and I also understand the idea behind a distributed source control system (so I don't need a sales pitch, thanks). What I'd like is a translation table from p4 command to equivalent git commands, as well as the "can't live without" commands that have no p4 equivalent.

Since I suspect every p4 user uses a different subset of p4, here are some of the things I regularly do in p4 that I'd like to be able to do in git that aren't immediately obvious from the docs I've looked at:

1. create multiple pending changelists in a single client. (`p4 change`)
2. edit a pending changelist. (also `p4 change`)
3. see a list of all of my pending changelists (`p4 changes -s pending`)
4. list of all of the changed files in my client (`p4 opened`) or in a pending changelist (`p4 describe`)
5. see a diff of a pending changelist (I use a wrapper script for this which uses `p4 diff` and `p4 describe`)
6. for a given file, see which submitted changelists affected which lines (`p4 annotate`)
7. for a given file, see a list of the descriptions of the changelists that affected the file (`p4 log`)
8. submit a pending changelist (`p4 submit -c`)
9. abort a pending changelist (`p4 revert`)

A lot of these revolve around "changelists". "changelist" is p4 terminology. What's the git equivalent term?

It sounds like branches might be what git users use in place of what p4 calls changelists. A bit confusing, since p4 also has something called a branch though they seem to be only vaguely related concepts. (Though I always thought p4's concept of a branch was pretty weird it is different yet again from the classic RCS concept of a branch.)

Anyway... I'm not sure how to accomplish what I normally do in p4 changelists with git's branches. In p4 I can do something like this:

```
$ p4 edit a.txt
$ p4 change a.txt
Change 12345 created.
```

At this point I have a changlist that contains a.txt. I can edit the description and continue working without submitting the changelist. Also, if it turns out that I need to make some changes to some other files, like say a bugfix in some other layer of the code, I can do that in the same client:

```
$ p4 edit z.txt
$ p4 change z.txt
Change 12346 created.
```

Now I have two separate changelists in the same client. I can work on these concurrently, and I don't need to do anything to "switch between" them. When it comes time to commit, I can submit them separately:

```
$ p4 submit -c 12346  # this will submit the changes to z.txt
$ p4 submit -c 12345  # this will submit the changes to a.txt
```

I can't figure out how to replicate this in git. From my experiments, it doesn't appear that `git add` is associated with the current branch. As far as I can tell, when I `git commit` it's going to commit all files that I `git add`-ed no matter what branch I was in at the time:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/laurence/git-playground/.git/
$ ls
a.txt  w.txt  z.txt
$ git add -A .
$ git commit
 Initial commit.
 3 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
 create mode 100644 w.txt
 create mode 100644 z.txt
$ vi a.txt z.txt 
2 files to edit
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   a.txt
#   modified:   z.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git branch aardvark
$ git checkout aardvark
M   a.txt
M   z.txt
Switched to branch 'aardvark'
$ git add a.txt 
$ git checkout master
M   a.txt
M   z.txt
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git branch zebra
$ git checkout zebra
M   a.txt
M   z.txt
Switched to branch 'zebra'
$ git add z.txt 
$ git status
# On branch zebra
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   a.txt
#   modified:   z.txt
#
$ git checkout aardvark
M   a.txt
M   z.txt
Switched to branch 'aardvark'
$ git status
# On branch aardvark
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   a.txt
#   modified:   z.txt
```

In this example, the aardvark and zebra branches seem to contain exactly the same set of changes, and based on the output of `git status` it appears that doing a commit in either will have the same effect. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You could just use perforce for your personal code assuming the free 5 clients is enough.

Comment: That's what I'd been doing, but I'd like to switch to something that's open-source and also used by open-source projects. I've been considering both git and Mercurial. I've been leaning towards git because it seems to have more momentum.

Comment: You'd do better to learn Git from scratch. The workflow prescribed by Git is very different to the workflow prescribed by Perforce. Translated workflows will be awkward, and trying to equate features will confound your understanding. Fortunately, the Git community offers a wealth of documentation for beginners, eg. http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: @ColonelPanic I can see your point, but the problem with such documentation is that it wastes time explaining things basic things that every Perforce user would already know. Reading such documentation is just as annoying as trying to read a tutorial on another programming language that spends a chapter explaining what variables are.

Comment: @ColonelPanic That said, I did read some other git documentation, including *Git From the Bottom Up* and *Git for Computer Scientists* that were actually quite useful. I've been using Git for a few years now (note when this question was originally asked), and I feel like the main problems with learning git are not lack of documentation, but poor nomenclature, internal inconsistency, badly overloaded commands, and certain unfinished parts that aren't ready for real use. I kind of wish someone would go and clean up all of the cruft, but that would annoy those who've grown used to it.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I haven't used perforce much so this may not be exactly be a 1:1 translation. Then again distributed source control systems like git and mercurial have a different workflow anyway so there really isn't (and there shouldn't) be a 1:1 translation. Anyway, here goes:

- Create multiple pending changelists -> Use branches instead. In git branches are light and quick, takes less than a second to create and typically less than two seconds to merge. Don't be afraid of branching and rebase often.

  ```
  git branch new-branch-name
  git checkout new-branch-name
  ```

  Or do it all in one line:

  ```
  git checkout -b new-branch-name
  ```
- See a list of all pending changelists -> Since the equivalent of multiple pending changelist is multiple branches just view the branches:

  ```
  git branch
  ```

  If you want to view remote branches as well:

  ```
  git branch -a
  ```

  It is considered good practice to immediately delete a branch after a successful merge so you don't have to keep track of which branch are pending to be merged and which have already been merged.
- List all changed files -> For a single pending "changelist" in a specific branch git has a concept of the index or cache. In order to commit a change you must first add files to this index. This allows you to manually select which group of files represent a single change or to ignore irrelevant files. To see the status of which files are added, or not to this index just do:

  ```
  git status
  ```
- See a diff of a pending changelist -> There are two parts to this. First to see a diff between the working directory and the index:

  ```
  git diff
  ```

  But if you want to know the diff between what you're typing now and the last commit then you are really asking for a diff between the working directory+index and the HEAD:

  ```
  git diff HEAD
  ```
- For a given file, see which submitted changelists affected which lines -> This is easy:

  ```
  git blame filename
  ```

  or even better, if you are in a windowing environment:

  ```
  git gui blame filename
  ```

  Git gui takes longer to parse the file (it was written in tcl instead of C) but it has lots of neat features including the ability to "time travel" back into the past by clicking on a commit ID. I only wish they'd implement a feature to "time travel" to the future so I can find out how a given bug will finally be resolved ;-)
- For a given file, see a list of the descriptions of the changelists that affected the file -> also easy:

  ```
  git log filename
  ```

  But git log is a much more powerful tool than just this. In fact most of my personal scripts piggyback off-of git log to read the repository. Read the man page.
- Submit a pending changelist -> Also easy:

  ```
  git commit
  ```

See my answer to a previous question to see my typical git workflow: [Learning Git. Need to know if I am on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558036/learning-git-need-to-know-if-i-am-on-the-right-track/3558626#3558626)

If you follow the workflow I outlined then you'll find tools like gitk to be much more valuable since it allows you to clearly see groups of changes.

---

### Additional answer:

Git is very flexible and there are several ways to do what you describe. The thing to remember is to always start a new branch for each feature you're working on. This means the master branch isn't touched so you can always go back to it to do bug fixes. Working in git one should almost always start with:

```
git checkout -b new-feature-a
```

Now you can edit file a.txt. To work concurrently on another feature do:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b new-feature-z
```

Now you can edit file z.txt. To switch back to a.txt:

```
git checkout new-feature-a
```

But wait, there are changes to new-feature-z and git won't let you switch branches. At this point you have two choices. The first is the simplest, commit all changes to the current branch:

```
git add .
git commit
git checkout new-feature-a
```

This is what I'd recommend. But if you are really not ready to commit the code, you can temporarily stash it:

```
git stash
```

Now you can switch to branch new-feature-a. To go back to the code you were working on just pop the stash:

```
git checkout new-feature-z
git stash pop
```

When all is done merge back all changes to master:

```
git merge --no-ff new-feature-a
git merge --no-ff new-feature-z
```

Because merges are so quick and easy (easy because conflicts are so rare and conflict resolution, when one does happen, not too hard) we use branches in git for everything.

Here's another example of a common use of branches in git that you don't see in other source control tools (except perhaps mercurial):

Need to keep changing your config files to reflect your dev environment? Then use a branch:

```
git checkout -b dev-config
```

Now edit your config files in your favourite editor then commit changes:

```
git add .
git commit
```

Now every new branch can start from the dev-config branch instead of master:

```
git checkout dev-config
git checkout -b new-feature-branch
```

Once you're done remove the edits in dev-config from new-feature-branch using interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i master
```

Delete the commits you don't want then save. Now you have a clean branch without custom config edits. Time to merge back to master:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff new-feature-branch
# because master have changed, it's a good idea to rebase dev-config:
git checkout dev-config
git rebase master
```

It should be noted that removing edits with `git rebase -i` even works when all changes happen in the same file. Git remembers changes, not file content*.

**note: actually, technically not entirely true but as a user that's what it feels like*

---

### More additional answer:

So, from you comments it looks like you want to have two branches to exist simultaneously so you can test how the combined code works. Well, this is a good way to illustrate the power and flexibility of branches.

First, a word on the implication of cheap branching and modifiable history on your workflow. When I was using CVS and SVN I was always a bit reluctant to commit. That's because committing unstable code would inevitably f**k up other people's working code. But with git I lost that fear. That's because in git other people won't get my changes until I merge them to master. So now I find myself committing code every 5 lines I write. You don't need perfect foresight to commit. You just need to change your mindset: commit-to-branch==add-to-changeset, merge-to-master==commit-changeset.

So, back to examples. Here's how I would do it. Say you have a branch `new-feature-z` and you want to test it with `new-feature-a`. I would just create a new branch to test it:

```
# assume we are currently in branch new-feature-z
# branch off this branch for testing
git checkout -b feature-z-and-feature-a
# now temporarily merge new-feature-a
git merge --no-ff new-feature-a
```

Now you can test. If you need to modify something to make feature-z work with feature-a then do so. If so you can merge back the changes to the relevant branch. Use `git rebase -i` to remove irrelevant changes from the merge.

Alternatively, you can also use git rebase to temporarily change the base of new-feature-z to point to new-feature-a:

```
# assume we are currently in branch new-feature-z
git rebase new-feature-a
```

Now the branch history is modified so that new-feature-z will be based off new-feature-a instead of master. Now you can test. Any changes committed in this branch will belong to the branch new-feature-z. If you need to modify new-feature-a just switch back to it and the rebase to get the new changes:

```
git checkout new-feature-a
# edit code, add, commit etc..
git checkout new-feature-z
git rebase new-feature-a
# now new-feature-z will contain new changes from new-feature-a
```

When you're done, simply rebase back to master to remove changes from new-feature-a:

```
# assume we are currently in branch new-feature-z
git rebase master
```

Don't be afraid to start a new branch. Don't be afraid to start a throwaway branch. Don't be afraid to throw away branches. And since merge==submit and commit==add-to-changeset don't be afraid to commit often. Remember, commit is a developer's ultimate undo tool.

Oh, and another thing, in git deleted branches still exist in your repository. So if you've accidentally deleted something that you later realise is useful after all you can always get it back by searching the history. So don't be afraid to throw away branches.

Comment: I tried to figure out how to use git branches to accomplish what I do with changelists in p4, but I haven't been successful. I added more details to the question.

Comment: Does each branch have its own "index", or is there a single index shared between the branches? My experiment seems to suggest the latter, but you say "a specific branch git has a concept of the index or cache" which suggests the former.

Comment: It's a different tool. You need a different workflow and with that a different mindset and habit. No git doesn't work the way you describe. It's branches and nothing else. But there are very powerful branch manipulation tools. I suggest you consider youself a newbie who doesn't know anything about source control and read the basic tutorials. Consider your current mindset "bad habbit" that you have to be re-educated against in git-land. Sorry..

Comment: So what do you do in git when you've got two things you want to work on concurrently (and in the same place, so you can test uncommitted changes against each other), but you want to commit them separately? Also, how can you edit a commit message before performing a commit? I can accept that the workflow is different, but you haven't said what the git-equivalent workflow is. Saying these are bad habits sounds an awful lot like trying to pass off a bug as a feature.

Comment: Read my updated answer. You're still thinking in terms of uncommitted changes when you should be thinking about unmerged branches.

Comment: The "bad habbit" comment was from reading Joel Spolsky's experience using mercurial: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/03/17.html

Comment: I found http://www.newartisans.com/2008/04/git-from-the-bottom-up.html and on page 22 it basically acknowledges that git can't do what I want, but suggests using "Stacked Git" to get something similar (and actually more powerful). The branching workflow you suggest seems to assume that I have perfect foresight, which I don't. I frequently get part way into a change and then discover that I need to make a separate change for what I'm working on to work. I want both changes in the same workspace so I can test them against each other, and I don't want to commit either in a non-working state.

Comment: Ah, so you want both changes to exist at the same time. No problem, create a temporary branch to test or (depending on what you want to do) use rebase. Remember, the majority of the effort is to change your thinking and get used to what git can do. Wait, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Your point about commit-to-branch=add-to-changeset and merge-to-master=commit-changeset is a good one. I was already aware that commits are much more common in a DVCS, but seeing it stated that way makes it much easier to internalize. Unfortunately, it's still much more heavy-weight than what I do in p4 where I can switch back and forth between a and z just by switching buffers in my editor -- no need to commit, switch branches or merge before testing, and no need to "merge changes back" if I need to modify either a or z.

Comment: Very extensive answer.  At what point should this be wikified?

Answer (score 2):

I suffer like you with the lack of the "changelist" concept which is not exactly the same as git branches.

I would write a small script that will create a changelist file with the list of files in that changelist.

Another command to submit just a certain changelist by simply calling git commit -a @change_list_contents.txt and then "git commit"

Hope that helps,
Elias

Comment: Yes, I have actually considered doing something like this, though at the time I asked this question I was new to git and so I wanted to know the "native" solution. Now I find that the main thing I miss is the ability to work on a commit message without actually committing. Thus could be solved by having a file to hold the "pending commit message", and perhaps some magic to automatically read it when writing a commit message.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves, the workflow I use is to commit imperfect commit messages (or even just "WIP") while I am focused on the work, then later amend then during my rebase. As commits are purely local, they do not need to be final until you make your branch available (by pushing it to your remote or similar).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough p4 experience to produce an actual cheat sheet, but there are at least some similarities to fall back on. A p4 "changeset" is a git "commit".

Changes to your local work space get added to the "index" with `git add`, and the index later gets committed with `git commit`. So the index is your pending changelist, for all intents and purposes.

You look at changes with `git diff` and `git status`, where `git diff` usually shows changes between the workspace and the index, but `git diff --cached` shows changes between the index and the repository (= your pending changelist).

For more in depth information, I recommend http://progit.org/book/. Since you know version control in general, you can probably skim a lot of it and extract the git-specific information...

Comment: I would disagree that "a p4 changeset is a git commit"; they're the closest equivalents, true, but a p4 changeset is much closer to a set of git commits. A p4 changeset represents a feature, whereas a git branch represents a feature.

Comment: @RJFalconer Erm. A "branch" is a branch in Perforce too, no? And a "changeset" is an atomic collection of changes to one or more files, very much like a commit? If not, what would you say is the p4 equivalent of commit?

Comment: I would say that p4 has no equivalent, simply because the degree of atomicity isn't the same; in git I can make a several changes in a given file then commit them in different commits (git add -p), thus separating refactoring/cleanup in the history from feature/bug fix. If I were to do this in p4 I'd have to develop the two separately. Even then my commits may not be continuous as other developers can submit in between them (unless I private branch, which involves oft-impractical duplicating on disk).

Comment: Disclaimer: I've only used p4 for a few months and it's quite possible that there's some feature of it that accomplishes this that I just haven't come across yet.

Comment: p4 changelists and p4 branches are logically the same as git commits and git branches.  p4 shelve is the equivalent of git stash.  Where they differ is in the implementation (i.e. distributed vs. client-server) and that difference results in p4 equivalent of git checkout involving multiple steps and considerable time.  The overhead is such that multiple branches are typically preserved locally on disk instead of doing the equivalent of git checkout.  p4 shelves are stored on the server rather in the local repo.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more lightweight alternative in git that could form part of your workflow; using the git staging area.

I often just make changes then submit as several commits (e.g. add debug statements, refactor, actually fix a bug). Rather than setting up your perforce changelists, then make changes, then submit, you can just make your changes then choose how to submit them (optionally using the git staging area).

You can commit particular files from the command line with:

```
git commit a.txt
git commit z.txt
```

Or explicitly staging the files first:

```
git add a.txt
git commit
git add z.txt
git commit
```

git gui will let you select lines or hunks from within files to build up a commit in the staging area. This is very useful if you have changes in one file that you want to be in different commits. Having moved from git to perforce and this is one thing that I really miss.

There is a small caveat to bear in mind with this workflow. If you make changes A and B to a file, test the file, then commit A then you haven't tested that commit (independently of B).

Comment: It's certainly true that git lets you do even finer-grained commits than perforce (ie: lines and hunks). The thing I (still) miss from perforce is the ability to have it keep track of the change description (aka commit message) for what I'm currently working on. For example, when I'm going to fix bug #12345 I'd creat a changelist saying I was doing that (but not submit aka commit it). Then as I worked on it, I'd update the change description to indicate what I'd done. Finally, when I'm done, I'd commit the changelist.

Comment: In git it seems the rough equivalent is to commit those tiny (often non-working) bits to a dev branch, and then once everything is ok to merge the changes up. This still feels much more tedious and clunky to me. Also, I still haven't really gotten used to the idea of committing code that doesn't even compile.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Curious if you got used to it in the meantime. I'm coming to Perforce from Git and I miss being able to commit every 15 minutes, then push when I'm ready.

Answer (score 1):

It's me from the future.

Now that I've been using git for many years, I thought it might be interesting
to see how I'd answer this question from my former self.

Specific answers are below, but the overarching theme is: **in git, feature branches
take on the role of perforce's changelists**. In many ways, they are more flexible, though
that flexibility means you often need to do a bit more typing, and there are
also more ways to make a mistake.

Branches in Perforce tend to be long-term, heavyweight things. You don't make
branches very often. In git, however, branches are cheap. In git, a branch is
little more than a pointer to a commit. In git, some branches are long-term,
like those in Perforce. A common example is `main` (or `master`).

However, it's common practice to also make short-lived feature (or topic)
branches. These branches usually remain "private", and instead of having
"pending changelists", you have one of these branches. You can add commits,
remove commits, reorder commits, and squash commits together. You can also
change where the branch is "attached" to the "target" branch. Most of this is
done with `git rebase -i`, which seems like a scary command, but is actually
pretty easy to use, and is very powerful.

I remember when I first started learning git, the idea of rewriting history
seemed like a terrible idea to me. However, other version control systems
(including perforce) do this as well, they just don't acknowledge it. For
example, if you have changes in your p4 client, and you "sync", it'll push your
changes "after" the newly synced changes that got pulled down. This is exactly
the same as a rebase!

Anyway, here are answers to the specific "How do I" questions above:

> create multiple pending changelists in a single client. (p4 change)

Use separate feature/topic branches, one for each thing you're working on.

> edit a pending changelist. (also p4 change)

I primarily use `git rebase -i` for this.

> see a list of all of my pending changelists (p4 changes -s pending)

Use `git branch` to list local branches. This will also list branches that
aren't your feature branches, so you may want to adopt a naming convention to
set your feature branches apart.

> list of all of the changed files in my client (p4 opened) or in a pending
> changelist (p4 describe)

You can use `git status` to see uncommited changes.

You can use `git diff --name-only` to see which files have changed between a
particular commit and another commit or your working tree. For example, if you
want to see what changed between your current branch and the branch `main`:

```bash
git diff --name-only main
```

> see a diff of a pending changelist (I use a wrapper script for this which
> uses p4 diff and p4 describe)

Use `git diff` without the `--name-only` option. You can also use `git difftool`, or other git diffing tools that aren't iincluded with git. I use
`git multidiff` with `vim-multidiff`.

> for a given file, see which submitted changelists affected which lines (p4
> annotate)

This can be done with `git blame`.

> for a given file, see a list of the descriptions of the changelists that
> affected the file (p4 log)

Using `git log` on a file does this.

> submit a pending changelist (p4 submit -c)

Purely in git, this would be done with `git merge`. For example:

```bash
git switch main
git merge feature-branch
```

I prefer to do a "semi-linear" merge, meaning I'll do two steps:

```bash
git switch feature-branch
git rebase main

git switch main
git merge --no-ff feature-branch
```

Though if there's only one commit on my feature branch, I'll just fast-forward
merge.

However, when working with a team with a git host like Github or GitLab, I
pretty much never use `git merge`. Instead, I'll submit a
pull-request/merge-request, and then (after code review) merge using the web UI
of the git host.

On GitLab, the way I create a merge request is to push my feature branch with
some extra push options. I have a shell script, `git-mr` which simplifies this.
The important part is:

```bash
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
git push \
    -o merge_request.create \
    -o merge_request.remove_source_branch \
    -u origin "$BRANCH_NAME:$BRANCH_NAME"
```

> abort a pending changelist (p4 revert)

To delete a feature branch:

```bash
git branch -D feature-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question specifically, but I don't know if you are aware that a 2 User, 5 Workspace version of perforce is free to download and use from the [perforce website](http://www.perforce.com/).

This way you can use perforce at home for your personal projects if you wish.  The one annoyance is the 5 workspaces which can be a bit limiting, but its pretty incredible to have perforce available for home use.

Comment: That's what I'd been doing, but I'd like to switch to something that's open-source and also used by open-source projects.

Answer (score 0):

Having used both Perforce and git fairly extensively, there's only one way I can see to get anywhere near Perforce changelists with git.

The first thing to understand is that to correctly implement this functionality in git in such a way that it's a not a complete kluge, e.g. trying to shoehorn it into branches, would require the following change: git would require multiple staging areas for a single branch.

Perforce changelists permit a workflow that simply has no equivalent in git.  Consider the following workflow:

```
Check out a branch
Modify file A and add it to changelist 1
Modify file B and add it to changelist 2
```

If you try to do this using branches in git you'll wind up with two branches, one of which has the changes to file `A`, the other has the changes to file `B`, but no place where you can see the changes to both files `A` and `B` at the same time.

The closest approximation I can see is to use `git add . -p` and then use the `'a'` and `'d'` sub-commands to select or reject entire files.  However that's not quite the same, and the difference here stems from a fundamental disparity in the general modus operandi of the two systems.

Git (and subversion, not that it matters for this discussion) allow a file to be changed without telling anyone about this ahead of time.  You just change a file, and then let git sort it all out when you commit the changes.  Perforce requires you to actively check out a file before changes are allowed, and it is for this reason that changelists have to exist.  In essence, Perforce requires you to add a file to the index before changing it.  Hence the necessity for multiple changelists in Perforce, and also the reason why git has no equivalent.  *It simply doesn't need them.*

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git p4`" learned four new hooks and also "`--no-verify`" option to bypass them (and the existing "`p4-pre-submit`" hook).

See [commit 1ec4a0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ec4a0a356f73ef0ab57d3903bd6667942a7052c), [commit 38ecf75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38ecf75244c4cab93ecb201afff8980c29f56ce8), [commit cd1e0dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd1e0dc47a5ab1520b823d051d23f60c89072349) (14 Feb 2020), and [commit 4935c45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4935c458c2ef301d720980eb94de4b631fe47128), [commit aa8b766](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa8b766a1393070fc85a585b875a4a4f34a08573), [commit 9f59ca4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f59ca4d6afc69aec09eeec10e823222f4d7507b), [commit 6b602a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b602a2f97bbf27c8858643efeabce23195414cb) (11 Feb 2020) by [Ben Keene (`seraphire`)](https://github.com/seraphire).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5f2ec21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f2ec211f629f5b1d9a85e924946ae2079fa96f7), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38ecf75244c4cab93ecb201afff8980c29f56ce8): add p4 submit hooks
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ben Keene</sup>
>
> The git command "`commit`" supports a number of hooks that support changing the behavior of the commit command.
>
> The `git-p4.py` program only has one existing hook, "`p4-pre-submit`".
>
> This command occurs early in the process.
>
> There are no hooks in the process flow for modifying the P4 changelist text programmatically.
>
> Adds 3 new hooks to `git-p4.py` to the submit option.
>
> The new hooks are:
>
> - **`p4-prepare-changelist`** - Execute this hook after the changelist file has been created.
>     The hook will be executed even if the `--prepare-p4-only` option is set.
>     This hook ignores the `--no-verify` option in keeping with the existing behavior of [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).
> - **`p4-changelist`** - Execute this hook after the user has edited the changelist.
>     Do not execute this hook if the user has selected the `--prepare-p4-only` option.
>     This hook will honor the `--no-verify`, following the conventions of [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).
> - `p4-post-changelist` - Execute this hook after the P4 submission process has completed successfully.
>     This hook takes no parameters and is executed regardless of the `--no-verify` option.
>
> It's return value will not be checked.
>
> The calls to the new hooks: `p4-prepare-changelist`, `p4-changelist`, and `p4-post-changelist` should all be called inside the try-finally block.

---

Before Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), the "`--prepare-p4-only`" option is supposed to stop after replaying one changeset, but kept going (by mistake?)

See [commit 2dfdd70](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2dfdd705ffd8c6dd1ef75abdfb64e1a08ad35a26) (12 May 2020) by [Ben Keene (`seraphire`)](https://github.com/seraphire).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7a8fec9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a8fec908a40bd009803de1617c90684e932f878), 02 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4.py`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2dfdd705ffd8c6dd1ef75abdfb64e1a08ad35a26): fix `--prepare-p4-only` error with multiple commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ben Keene</sup>
>
> When using `git p4 submit` with the `--prepare-p4-only` option, the program should prepare a single p4 changelist and notify the user that more commits are pending and then stop processing.
>
> A bug has been introduced by the `p4-changelist` hook feature that causes the program to continue to try and process all pending changelists at the same time.
>
> The function `applyCommit` returns `True` when applying the commit was successful and the program should continue.
>   However, when the optional flag `--prepare-p4-only` is set, the program should stop after the first application.
>
> Change the logic in the run method for P4Submit to check for the flag `--prepare-p4-only` after successfully completing the `applyCommit` method.
>
> If more than 1 commit is pending submission to P4, the method will properly prepare the P4 changelist, however it will still exit the application with an exitcode of 1.
>
> The [current documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20514004ddf1a3528de8933bc32f284e175e1012/Documentation/git-p4.txt#L336-L341) does not define what the exit code should be in this condition.