# Git-p4 submit error: No files to submit

Tags: git, submit, perforce

When using git-p4 command to submit git changes to perforce, I got an error saying "No files to submit". 
I use --prepare-p4-only switch, and find out git prepares a submission without affected files, but the changed files are checked out in perforce client workspace, and the diff is attached in the prepared submission details as well.
I submit a file directly using perforce client, and it is working fine. No perforce permission issue.

So what would be the root cause?

Best Regards,

Comment: Speaking of `--prepare-p4-only`, Git 2.28 (Q3 2020) fixes a bug for that option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61431646/6309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause: git-p4 has bug/unfinished work for multiple depot path support. In sum you may introduce multiple depot paths during clone, sync and rebase, but submit function only handle one depot path. Werid......

For example, if you create the git repository with below command:

```
git-p4 clone --use-client-spec //Depot/path/a //Depot/path/b gitrepo
```

Git-p4 will maintain the two depot paths in git log messages and leverage them for upcoming sync and rebase operation.

But when you would like to submit git changes back to Perforce with git-p4 submit, it only takes care of //Depot/path/a and totally ignore //Depot/path/b. My case is as this, and since one change in my git repository is to be submit to //Depot/path/b, it always fails at submission phase, because git-p4 thinks the depot path is not in scope and will ignore the file modifications when preparing the changelist description, hence Perforce complains that no files to be submit.

I made a small change to workaround this problem in git-p4 script, and will try to sumbit this patch to Git later on.