# Develop features in different branches, but work with the accumulated code change?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have understood that it is best to develop each feature and bug fix in a separate branch, to make it easier for the repository owner to evaluate pull requests.

My workflow for this is that I

- checkout the master branch
- create a new branch
- develop a feature
- commit the feature
- pull request the feature
- check out the master branch again and rinse and repeat with the next feature

This works OK. But what if I when I am working on my second, third or fourth feature, want to work with the code base that has the accumulated changes from previous branches? But I don't want to include those changes when I commit this branch.

It might be that the first branch fixed something that had broken. When I am working on the second branch, I need to be working with the accumulated code base from the previous branch, but when I commit the second branch, I just want to commit the changes that I am working on now in my second branch.

Does this type of workflow make sense?
How can I use git to work like this?

Comment: I tend to do `git checkout -b combined <startpoint>; git cherry-pick ...long list of stuff...` but I have not yet developed a way to make this work the way I really want it to, which probably involves a script where I just list which features I want combined, and then it automates rebuilding the "combined branch" every time I change something in one of the branches that it combines.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656351/git-for-perforce-users/3656678#3656678. I don't want to flag this as duplicate because your question is only related to my "Additional answer" section. Read that section. Basically you can merge branches into another temporary branch for testing. Git is to source code what promises are to javascript - it makes code composeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are few ways to do it:

- #### [Patches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)

  Patches are the diffs generated per commit.
  In other words: patch will include the changes in each commit as separate diff file.
  Once the patches are generated you can apply them to any given branch of your wish.

  ```
  git format-patch HEAD~X # generate the last X commits as patch
  ```

now you will have separate file with the commit code and you can change branch and `apply` the patch

```
    git checkout <new branch>
    git apply *.patch
    #or:
    git am *.patch
```

- #### [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

  `cherry-pick` is simply picking any desired commit to any branch.
  Due to the way git uses commits it does not attach them you can simply **pick** them to any given branch.
  You can use many `commit` per `cherry-pick`.

  ```
  git checkout <branch name>
  git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 commit3 ...
  ```

This will "import" the desired commits into your current branch.

Comment: Third way: merge the branches into another temporary branch.

Comment: But he doesn't want the current branch so it will not help if i understood you currectly. your

Comment: I didn't say he should commit the temporary branch. Just use it for testing then merge them separately.

Comment: Which is the simpler and more common approach? cherry-picking seems simpler to work with to me. I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: yep cherry pick is very simple